# What are consequences of changing Record Type Name

Tags: custom-object, administration, record-type, change-set, record

In my full org I have a record type with label name as ABC and its record type name is ABC_XXX. I also have a DEV org with the same record type names in there. I would like to changes the record type label as DEF and record type name as DEF_XXX.

I would then want to push the record type changes to FULL org from DEV. what will happen to already existing record with the record type as ABC? Would there be any changes to them? Would those record be gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change sets automatically update the names and labels of record types that were pushed by a change set or that existed in the sandbox as a result of creating or refreshing a Sandbox. All existing records in the sandbox will have their record types updated accordingly. If the record type was created independently in both orgs, it's likely that you'll end up with a "duplicate" record type in your sandbox. In that case, you can delete either record type and merge it back into the other record type on the confirmation screen. In either case, no records will be lost, because deleting, renaming, or merging record types does not result in the deletion of any records (besides, of course, the record type itself).

Comment: I do not have any record in DEV, only FULL has record. I would just be renaming the record type label and name and push it to FULL. I guess in this case records gets updated automatically and I do not have to worry about, is that correct?

Comment: @Rdvsm That's perfectly fine. Like I said, the worst case scenario is that you end up with a duplicate, in which case you can delete and replace it with the correct version.

Comment: What I have encountered (v41, Winter '18) is that when you try do deploy the change set you get an error message saying that it is trying to create a duplicate record type ("label").  My solution ?  In the target org, rename manually the record type API name, *then* deploy your change set.

Answer (score 0):

The record types are related to the record by record type ID, not the developer name, so you won't have to worry about existing records losing the relationship. However, if you use the RecordType.DeveloperName in any of your formulas, you may need to update the formulas to reflect the new name -- since it's just a string literal in the formula, it probably won't trigger a warning.

Comment: I searched the record type name in my eclipse where I downloaded all the components. I did not find the record type name in any formula field. I thought the formula field gets updated if we change API names of fields used in them. Is this the same case with record type name? How can record type name will be used in Formula field?

Comment: @Rdvsm You can use it via [$RecordType](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_understanding_global_variables.htm) global variable or by the RecordType field variable (depending on whatever it is you're doing, exactly). In either case, the result is a string comparison, which can break things. This could also include some types of workflow rules, etc.